# Change Column order in mobile view(wordpress). It is possible?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, mobile

i have a question here. I wanted to change website column order on the MOBILE. I try using javascript but seems is not working is something wrong with my code? Im using wordpress

Here is current desktop view : [a] [b] [c]

Current mobile view is something like this.

[a]

[b]

[c]

i wanted my column to appear like this

[b]

[a]

[c]

here is my code

```
<script>
  var $iW = $(window).innerWidth();
  if ($iW < 480){
     $('.b').insertBefore('.a');
  }else{
     $('.b').insertAfter('.a');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 html columns with container div like

```
<div class="for_desktop">
[a]
[b]
[c]
</div>

<div class="for_mobile">
[b]
[a]
[c]
</div>
```

Write Css Like :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   .for_desktop{ display:none;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
   .for_mobile{ display:none;}
}
```

Note : width will be change (you set as you need).